# MSys2 Mingw --major-image-version

Tags: cmake, mingw, msys2

I am trying to build C++ CMake based project. I have managed to build it on Windows using MSVC. However, I want to build it using MinGw. I installed MSys2 and using pacman, all needed packages where installed.

I have CMaked the project successfully. However, when calling make:

```
[ 51%] Linking CXX executable osrm-extract.exe
/C/msys64/mingw64/bin/cmake.exe -E remove -f CMakeFiles/osrm-extract.dir/objects.a
/C/msys64/mingw64/bin/ar.exe cr CMakeFiles/osrm-extract.dir/objects.a "CMakeFiles/osrm-extract.dir/src/tools/extract.cpp.obj"
/C/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe  -Werror=all -Werror=extra  -Werror=uninitialized -Werror=unreachable-code -Werror=unused-variable -Werror=unreachable-code -Wno-error=cpp -Wpedantic -Werror=strict-overflow=1 -Wno-error=maybe-uninitialized -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fdiagnostics-color=auto -fPIC -ftemplate-depth=1024 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -std=c++14 -O3 -DNDEBUG   -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,--disable-new-dtags  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles/osrm-extract.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o osrm-extract.exe -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  libosrm_extract.a -lboost_program_options-mt libosrm_guidance.a -lbz2 -lboost_regex-mt -lboost_date_time-mt -lboost_chrono-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_iostreams-mt -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_system-mt -lexpat /C/msys64/mingw64/bin/lua53.dll -lz -ltbb -ltbbmalloc -lbz2 -lboost_regex-mt -lboost_date_time-mt -lboost_chrono-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_iostreams-mt -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_system-mt -lexpat /C/msys64/mingw64/bin/lua53.dll -lz -ltbb -ltbbmalloc -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.gold.exe: --major-image-version: unknown option
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.gold.exe: use the --help option for usage information
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The error says  `--major-image-version: unknown option`. Why does this happen ? How to overcome it?

I saw this thread https://github.com/projectNe10/Ne10/issues/81 which suggest to add `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` but it does not make a difference.

Comment: Did you try setting the `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` at the top of your CMake to `Generic`?

Comment: This should be added somewhere close to the top of your CMakeLists.txt.